# Scrollbar not showing all content

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scrollbar

I have a unordered list like this,

```
return (
      <div className="tailor-tabs">
        <ul className="tailor-tab-list ">
          {children.map((child) => {
            const { label } = child.props;

            return (
              <TailorTab
                activeTab={activeTab}
                key={label}
                label={label}
                onClick={onClickTabItem}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <div className="tailor-tab-content">
          {children.map((child) => {
            if (child.props.label !== activeTab) return undefined;
            return child.props.children;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

And now I want to make that `unordered list` scrollable horizontally. 
And I am making it horizontally scrollable like this,

```
.tailor-tab-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

but the problem here is I cannot see the whole list, it shows most of the items but some items are hidden and can not be scrolled. like this,
[image] 
Why is that? Any help?
After the list is made, it shows like this
[image]

Comment: `overflow-y` is for vertical scrolling. Use `overflow-x` instead.

Comment: Does not make any difference

Comment: Can you include an example of the resulting HTML from your react code?

Comment: Please have a look at the updated question at the end